# golang: Cannot see Printf output in Cloudwatch logs

Tags: go, terraform, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a small http server written in go which I am trying to deploy on ECS. The deployment is failing and I am trying to check the logs to see what is going on but I can see no output on stdout.

```golang
func getRoot(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("got / request\n")
    io.WriteString(w, "This is it!\n")
}

func healthcheck(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("got / healthcheck\n")
    io.WriteString(w, "Alive!\n")
}

func main(){
    

    http.HandleFunc("/", getRoot)
    http.HandleFunc("/healthcheck", healthcheck)

    fmt.Println("Listening on port 80")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
    if errors.Is(err, http.ErrServerClosed) {
        fmt.Printf("server closed\n")
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error starting server: %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

}
```

The logging configuration is done through Terraform. I am configuring a simple log group

```yaml
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "service" {
  name              = "service-prod"
  retention_in_days = var.logs_retention_days

  tags = var.cost_tags
}
```

which I am using in the container definitions

```yaml
logConfiguration = {
      logDriver = var.log_driver

      options = merge(
        var.log_options,
        {
          "awslogs-region" = data.aws_region.current.name
          "awslogs-group"  = concat(aws_cloudwatch_log_group.service.*.name, [""])[0]
        }
      )
    }
```

the entry point to the container is

```bash
go run main.go
```

the only output I can see in Cloudwatch is the following:

```bash
    
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/eventbridge v1.18.5
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2 v1.17.5
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ecs v1.24.0
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/cloudwatchlogs v1.20.5
go: downloading github.com/spf13/cobra v1.6.1
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config v1.18.15
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials v1.13.15
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sts v1.18.5
go: downloading github.com/aws/smithy-go v1.13.5
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/internal/v4a v1.0.21
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/internal/configsources v1.1.29
go: downloading github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath v0.4.0
go: downloading github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/ec2/imds v1.12.23
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/internal/ini v1.3.30
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/sso v1.12.4
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ssooidc v1.14.4
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/internal/presigned-url v1.9.23
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/internal/endpoints/v2 v2.4.23
```

which is expected since it's downloading the imports I guess. Is this behavior expected?

// EDIT
My image is based on the official golang image

Comment: If you take the exact same docker image and run it locally, do you see your Printf output there?

Comment: yes they are printed out perfectly and the service runs as expected

Comment: The expected behavior is you would see the same logs on AWS that you would see in the local docker container. It's strange to me that your docker image is downloading dependencies at startup, instead of having those included when the image was built, via the Dockerfile. Does it show those same `downloading` log statements when you run it locally?

Comment: yes it shows the exact same download statements. I guess this is because I am not running `go build` before?

Comment: I just fixed it. I assigned more CPUs and memory to the ECS task.... I had assigned .25 vCPUs and 512 MB of memory

Comment: Perhaps the container was taking too long to start up (because you are doing stuff at startup that you should really be doing during the image build), and that was causing the health check to timeout.